# split data to columns on years

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have excel sheet having data from 1920 to 2020 for each day.

```
Date                      value
1/24/2020  6:00:00 AM     11.88
1/23/2020  6:00:00 AM     32.99
.
.
.
.
.
1/2/1920  6:00:00 AM       12.2
1/1/1920  6:00:00 AM       33.22
```

But I want it to be in excel like

[image: Output]

NOTE: Dates can be in any range suppose from 1920 to 2020 first month, from 1940 to 2020 sixth month.

is there any method in pandas that can help in this....
Example Excel uploaded here: https://a.uguu.se/iGm1Nb61wc0H_Exampledata

Comment: Please create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question that someone can copy and paste into a Python REPL. That will help others to answer your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need [`read_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html) with [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html), sorting years in columns and last add means to `MultiIndex`:

```
df = pd.read_excel('iGm1Nb61wc0H_Exampledata.xls')

df1 = df.pivot_table(index=df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m/%d'),
                     columns=df['Date'].dt.year,
                     values='Value').sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
df1.columns = [df1.mean(), df1.columns]
```